# Bxslider - how to remove slide?

Tags: jquery, bxslider

How to remove slide from bxslider?

HTML:

```
<ul class="bx_slider">
<li>1 - <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></li>
<li>2 - <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></li>
<li>3 - <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".bx_slider").bxSlider({
pager: false
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2srcv28/

Comment: why do you want to remove the slides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
var slider = $(".bx_slider").bxSlider({
    pager: false
});

$('.remove').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    slider.reloadSlider();
});
```

Take a look at this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2srcv28/1/)

Hope it may helps you.

(the solution was in the [official doc](http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider-settings))

---

#### Edit:

As asked in comment the jump, when the last slide is removed, to the first one was not desired.

A possible solution would be

```
$('.remove').click(function() {
    
    $(this).parent().remove();
    
    slider.reloadSlider({
        pager: false,
        startSlide: slider.getCurrentSlide()-1 // Starts the slider on the previous slide
    });
});
```

Result can be check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o2srcv28/7/), or [here (with more slides)](http://jsfiddle.net/o2srcv28/6/)

Comment: If you remove slide 3 jumps back to slide 1 instead of 2. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Because of infiniteLoop bxslider script cloning some <li>, lets say if you made 10 slides, in html will be much more slides and if you try to remove cloned one, its gets messy. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o2srcv28/8/ (cloned ones with grey background, try to remove from them). Any advice?

Comment: @Tomas I think the best solution is to set `infiniteLoop:false`. I know it's a huge change in the behavior of the slider but the simplest way to fix it. As the clones don't have the same index as the "reals" elements I don't see an easy way to solve this problem.

Comment: OK. Thank You for your help!